# How to aggregate median and standard deviation in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as func

cols = ("id","size")

result = df.groupby(*cols).agg({
    func.max("val1"),
    func.median("val2"),
    func.std("val2")
})
```

But it fails in the line `func.median("val2")` with the message that `median` cannot be found in `func`. The same happens to `std`.

Answer (score 5):

For median you should use `approxQuantile` for 0.5.

For std the operation you are looking for is `stddev`, `stddev_samp`, or `stddev_pop`. All of this is fairly clear in the docs. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html

Comment: Or alternatively use `F.expr('percentile(val2, array(0.5))')[0]` for median.